# Dispatcher servlet not found. mvn install fails with file not found

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

I have simple spring project using spring mvc. I have changed the dispatcher servlet name but mvn install fails with error.

Error stack trace : IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]

1)web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" >

 <display-name>Order Activation Snapshot</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>        
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/data-source-cfg.xml,
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>

    </context-param>


    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Spring Security Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

2)mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

      <context:component-scan base-package="org.o7planning.tutorial.springmvcsecurity.controller" />
      <context:annotation-config />

      <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
          <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
          <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
      </bean>

    </beans>
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

[File structure in my code base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KJjz.png)

Comment: Do you have any test cases also in your applicaition?

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatcher servlet name should be unique. 
You likely told your compiler/Intepreter somewhere in your code(haven't seen it here) to look for **dispatcher-servlet.xml** at **/WEB-INF/**. But seems you named your dispatcher with **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**. The **java.io.FileNotFoundException** exception might be as a result. 
Two things: Either you go to where you had **dispatcher-servlet.xml** and replace it with **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml** or you do the following:

Replace your dispatcher servlet name:

```
mvc-dispatcher-servlet
```

with

```
dispatcher-servlet
```

everywhere.

Add  **.xml** extension to **dispatcher-servlet** where need be.

For instance, in your **web.xml**, you can do the following changes:

```
...

<!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>        
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/data-source-cfg.xml,
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml <!--changed here -->
    </param-value>

</context-param>


<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> <!--changed here -->
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> <!--changed here -->
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

...
```

Note. I commented lines I made change on.

Comment: Thanks Edwardo for jumping on this, i had purposely changed dispatcher servlet name. As far as I see only web.xml tell which servlet to pickup and there I have mentioned the correct servlet i.e. "mvc-dispatcher" that should be postfixed by "-servlet.xml", am I missing anything?

Comment: @JavaTechno I see. So have you got the problem solved?

Comment: I guess you have 'dispatcher-servlet' somewhere in your Project. Try search the whole project for that String. Or start by looking at your Java classes

Comment: I@JavaTechno If you created an object of type 'ApplicationContext' or something Context in one of your Java classes, then check there. Because you might have had something like this:               ApplicationContext context =
     new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"dispatcher-servlet.xml"});

Comment: I did search the whole work space but didn't get any reference to "dispatcher-servlet". App is somehow expecting it by default or my newly created servlet is not correctly done. Do you want me to share the code also, if it helps?

Comment: That would be great. What if you change from mvc-dispatcher-servlet to dispatcher-servlet? From my experience you can use "any-name"-servlet.xml. But has to be the same everywhere.

Comment: ya thats what I felt but somehow didn't worked, let me change back to default servlet name, will keep you posted.